# Form state redirect to node path plus fragment

Tags: 8, forms

How can I redirect a form to the canonical node path + fragment?

Redirect: /nodepathalias#tag

```
$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',
  array('node' => $node->id()),
));
```

Where should I add the fragment information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third argument of the [setRedirect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.3.x) function:

> array $options: (optional) An associative array of additional options.
>   See \Drupal\Core\Url for the available keys.

And if you check that doc:

> @param array $options   (optional) An associative array of additional
>   URL options, with the   following elements:
>
> - 'query': An array of query key/value-pairs (without any URL-encoding)
>     to append to the URL.
> - 'fragment': A fragment identifier (named anchor) to append to the URL.
>     Do not include the leading '#' character.
> - 'absolute': Defaults to FALSE. Whether to force the output to be an
>     absolute link (beginning with http:). Useful for links that will be
>     displayed outside the site, such as in an RSS feed.
> - 'attributes': An associative array of HTML attributes that will be
>     added to the anchor tag if you use the \Drupal\Core\Link class to make
>     the link.
> - 'language': An optional language object used to look up the alias
>     for the URL. If $options['language'] is omitted, it defaults to the
>     current language for the language type LanguageInterface::TYPE_URL.
> - 'https': Whether this URL should point to a secure location. If not
>     defined, the current scheme is used, so the user stays on HTTP or HTTPS respectively. TRUE enforces HTTPS and FALSE enforces HTTP.

In your case you should use just `fragment`:

```
$options = [
  'fragment'   => 'tag',
];

$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',
  ['node' => 8],
  $options
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add 'fragment' in third argument of **setRedirect** method,  **$options** (@see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x).

You can see how this option is used in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x , in the method **toUriString()**

Example:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',
  array('node' => $node->id()),
  ['fragment' => 'tag']
));
```